# php scientific notation format

Tags: php, printf

Trying to format a scientific number in PHP:

```
sprintf('%1.2E',$var)
```

This gets me to `5.01E+1`

I am trying to print 2 digits after the + sign

The parser requires the number format to be:
`5.01E+01` instead of `5.01E+1`

Is it possible to achieve this format with `sprintf`?
Is there any other method that can achieve this?

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method as far as I know. But with a little bit of Regex black magic you can do something like this:

```
preg_replace('/(E[+-])(\d)$/', '${1}0$2', sprintf('%1.2E',$var));
```

Notice that I just wrapped your call to `sprintf()` with an appropriate call to `preg_replace()`. If the regular expression does not match it will leave the output from `sprintf()` as is.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a way to do it solely with `sprintf` but I believe the following would be closer to the *"correct"* way to do it.  The following calculates the exponent from the base-10 logarithm.

You can then pass the original value (dividing by 10 to the power of the exponent) ***and*** the exponent to the `sprintf` function as a float and an integer respectively.  You can force the positive `+` sign remembering that it counts towards the character / padding length.

```php
function scientificNotation($val){
    $exp = floor(log($val, 10));
    return sprintf('%.2fE%+03d', $val/pow(10,$exp), $exp);
}
```

[**demo / test cases :**](http://ideone.com/2E84dZ)

```php
scientificNotation(5.1);     // 5.10E+00
scientificNotation(50.1);    // 5.01E+01
scientificNotation(500.1);   // 5.00E+02
scientificNotation(0.0051);  // 5.10E-03
```

Answer (score -1):

The above answers both work great.

Also found out I can use:

```
 $var_formatted =  shell_exec("printf '%1.2E' $var");
```

which could be the cleanest given the script has the permissions to execute commmands.

The E+nn format is the default output format for the linux shell printf.

From the shell:

```
:~$ echo `printf '%1.2E' 500`
5.00E+02
:~$ echo `printf '%1.2E' 5`
5.00E+00
:~$ echo `printf '%1.2E' 0.05`
5.00E-02
```

Comment: as long as you can trust `$var` to be a sanitised number type :)

Comment: @Emissary very good point. If `$var` comes from user input, and the user sets the value `0; rm -rf /`, bad things could happen. See also https://www.revshells.com/